# Reopen app on startup

Tags: java, android

Is it possible when a user shuts down his phone while the app is running on the background to reopen the app when they start the phone?

I read something about putting an intent in user manifest but i couldn't find the solution for my problem..

anyone who knows how to do this?

Comment: create BroadcastReceiver for reboot and start app from BroadcastReceiver

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2784441/1793339

Comment: You can refer the following

[android-start-service-on-boot][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690350/android-start-service-on-boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should to create BroadcastReceiver like this link:
[Trying to start a service on boot on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android)

2) Start activity from Bradcastreceiver like this:
[Start Activity inside onReceive BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468463/start-activity-inside-onreceive-broadcastreceiver)

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Go through this link...

Broadcstrecevier can help you.

[broadcastreceiver in case of android device switched off and on not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073461/broadcastreceiver-in-case-of-android-device-switched-off-and-on-not-working)